# How to add password authentication to working OpenVPN server?

Tags: active-directory, openvpn

I have already working OpenVPN server, which connects 25 branches. Config is below.
Our company has outsourcing developers, and they need to access servers in DMZ.
How do I add N number of users(developers) and make password based authentication for them, on top of this config?
More preferrably users from Active Directory.

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh1024.pem
tls-server
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ta.key 0
tls-timeout 120
auth SHA1
cipher BF-CBC

server 10.255.1.0 255.255.255.0

client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd

route   10.2.0.0        255.255.0.0
route   10.3.0.0        255.255.0.0
route   10.4.0.0        255.255.0.0
route   10.5.0.0        255.255.0.0
route   10.6.0.0        255.255.0.0
route   10.10.0.0       255.255.0.0
route   10.8.0.0        255.255.0.0
route   10.27.0.0       255.255.0.0
route   10.7.0.0        255.255.0.0
route   10.11.0.0       255.255.0.0
route   10.12.0.0       255.255.0.0
route   10.13.0.0       255.255.0.0
route   10.14.0.0       255.255.0.0
route   10.15.0.0       255.255.0.0
route   10.16.0.0       255.255.0.0
route   10.17.0.0       255.255.0.0
route   10.18.0.0       255.255.0.0
route   10.19.0.0       255.255.0.0
route   10.20.0.0       255.255.0.0
route   10.21.0.0       255.255.0.0
route   10.22.0.0       255.255.0.0
route   10.23.0.0       255.255.0.0
route   10.24.0.0       255.255.0.0
route   10.25.0.0       255.255.0.0
#route  10.255.1.0      255.255.255.0

push "route 10.1.0.0 255.255.254.0"
push "route 10.1.200.0 255.255.255.0"



keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
max-clients 255
client-to-client
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
log /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
verb 3
mute 20

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a plugin. There is an auth-ldap plugin, and also an auth-pam plugin (I have only used the latter). The relevant config options are:

```
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-auth-ldap.so <config-file>
username-as-common-name  # These two allow authentication
client-cert-not-required # without a client certificate, if you want
duplicate-cn # Allow the same client cert or same user/password to connect multiple times
```

That's pretty much it!